# ¿Cómo aplicar filtro a un campo solo cuando hay registros en una tabla ligada con outer join?

Tags: sql

```
  SELECT sum(cast(r.importe as float)) suma
     , r.oficina
     , r.referencia
     , r.moneda_id
     , sum(cast(d.montante as float))
  FROM envio_remesa er
    INNER JOIN Remesa r
      ON er.id = r.envio_remesa_id
    LEFT JOIN documento d
      ON d.remesa_id = r.id
  WHERE r.envio_remesa_id = 3 
    AND r.tipo_doc='201' and d.cod_fac<>2 //AQUI ES EL FALLO
  GROUP BY oficina, referencia, r.moneda_id 
  ORDER BY oficina ASC
```

Mis tablas están compuesta de esta manera:

- 1 envio de remesa puede tener N remesas.
- 1 remesa puede tener N documentos.

El tema es que estoy intentando filtrar todos esos campos del `select`. El fallo viene cuando pongo `d.cod_fac<>2`, me filtra bien los que son distintos de dos, hasta ahí bien; pero hay remesas que no tienen documentos, entonces al comprobar con `d.cod_fac<>2` las deja fuera del resultado también y no las tiene en cuenta.

¿Cómo podría arreglar esto?

Me gustaría incluir las distintas de 2, y si no tiene documentos también

Comment: ¿Algo así  `AND (d.cod_fac<>2  OR d.cod_fac IS NULL)`  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clave para formular la consulta de manera correcta es recordar que, al utilizar cualquier `outer join`, cuando la tabla no tiene coincidencias, **todos sus campos tendrán valor `null`** en el conjunto de datos de resultado.

Entonces en SQL se plantea de manera casi idéntica a como lo expresas en lenguaje coloquial: quieres aquellas filas cuyo documento `cod_fac` sea distinto de dos, o no haya registro en la tabla `documento` (en otras palabras, que todos sus campos sean `null`).

Pero no hace falta comprobar todos los campos, solamente alguno que no pueda tener valor `null`, por ejemplo, algo como:

```
(d.cod_fac <> 2 or d.id is null)
```

Hay algunas cosas a tener en cuenta:

- Dado que la cláusula `where` tiene varias condiciones, estoy encerrando esta condición entre paréntesis. Lee la documentación de tu motor para asegurarte cuál es la precedencia de los operadores booleanos (and, or), ya que en algunos motores podrías dejarlo sin paréntesis.
- Como desconozco la estructura de la tabla, no estoy utilizando el mismo campo comparando el mismo campo `cod_fac` para evaluar si es `null`, eso funcionaría solo si el campo está declarado como `not null`. Por lo mismo, estoy utiliznado un hipotético campo `id` que sería la llave primaria y, por tanto, tendría el atributo `not null`. Eso me garantiza que mantengo bien la lógica de solo dejar pasar aquellos registros que *no tengan documento*. Si el campo `cod_fac` tiene el atributo `not null`, puede utilizarse igualmente en la condición, por ejemplo:

  ```
    (d.cod_fac <> 2 or d.cod_fac is null)
  ```

Poniendo todas las piezas juntas, una posible solución sería, entonces:

```
SELECT   sum(cast(r.importe as float)) suma
       , r.oficina
       , r.referencia
       , r.moneda_id
       , sum(cast(d.montante as float))
  FROM envio_remesa er
       INNER JOIN Remesa r ON er.id = r.envio_remesa_id
       LEFT JOIN documento d ON d.remesa_id = r.id
 WHERE r.envio_remesa_id = 3 
   AND r.tipo_doc='201' 
   and (    d.cod_fac <> 2 
         or d.id is null
       )
 GROUP BY oficina, referencia, r.moneda_id 
 ORDER BY oficina
```